# No of sample are more then number of features/dimension while using PCA

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, pca, image-compression

Hi I have training data of 1200 arrays and (92, 144) size each ranging from -2.5 to 2.5. I want to compress the size of each individual array by applying PCA. So I have flatten the array and this was my resulting training data (1200, 13248). But the problem is I have less number of training sample compare to my array size. When I uses 95% variance its using only 90 components with the resulting shape of (1200, 90), and when I inverse transform it to get the original shape back, I'm getting really good result. I compared it with original array using RMSE which is having less value of RMSE. So I just want to know is it worth compressing data using PCA even with less sample or should I produce more duplicate sample and then do it. Results are coming good after inversing so I'm not sure whether I'm doing something wrong or not.

Here's my code for PCA:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca = PCA(.95)

lower_dimensional_data = pca.fit_transform(np.array(a)) # a is training data of shape (1200, 13248)
lower_dimensional_data.shape #output (1200, 90)

approximation = pca.inverse_transform(lower_dimensional_data)
```

And here's my code for checking RMSE

```
err = (original_array[499] - approximation[499].reshape(92,144))**2
err_total = err.sum()
err = ((err_total/(92*144))**(1/2)).values
```